# Spring: Why method annotated with @PostConstruct cannot be static?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, postconstruct

I am reading documentation about `@PostConstruct` on this site: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-postconstruct-predestroy

It is written:

> The method annotated with @PostConstruct can have any access level but
> it can't be static.

Can someone tell me why method annotated with this annotation cannot be static?

Comment: Spring classes are singletons by default so there is only 1 instance, it makes no difference, it is effectively static without the static keyword.

The actual class spring uses will be a proxy around the class you have specified.

Comment: @EssexBoy it makes a world of difference. A `static` method cannot access instance variables, which are often used in `@PostConstruct` methods. Also it would lead to issues if a bean would have a scope like request or session as `static` would be on class level and not on instance level.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the name of the method already says what it does.

**PostConstruct**, this method will be called after the constructor. It can not be static because static methods can not access non static variables, methods and etc.

If you need something static to be run once, you can use static blocks.

Comment: Note: PostConstruct will not always is calling after the constructor. PostConstruct can be called without calling bean constructor. E.g. when we add the same bean to application context but with another qualifier name. In this case constructor will be called once while PostConstruct multiple times.

Comment: @MaksymPecheniuk "PostConstruct will not always is calling after the constructor. PostConstruct can be called without calling bean constructor." - That does not make sense.  It isn't possible to call a `PostConstruct` method (or any other instance method) on an object before it is constructed.

Comment: Sorry, my fault for bad description. Constructor is called first for sure. But it is possible that constructor will be called once while postConstruct will be called multiple times.

Answer (score 3):

> Can someone tell me why method annotated with this annotation cannot
> be static?

A method marked with `@PostConstruct` is a method that Spring is supposed to invoke after creating the bean instance.  The method is generally used to do some post construction configuration of the instance.  It would make no sense for that method to be static because a static method may not interact with any instance state in any instances of the class.